# Limit of $a_n = \frac{2^n +3^n}{3^n+4^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = \frac{2^n +3^n}{3^n+4^n}$ be a sequence. Calculate the  limit of a sequence. The solutions says that the limit of this sequence is 0. But, I think $2^n + 3^n \geq 2*2^n = 4^n$ and $3^n+4^n \leq 2*4^n$. So $a_n = \frac{2^n +3^n}{3^n+4^n} \geq \frac{4^n}{2*4^n} = \frac{1}{2}$ which is a contradiction to the fact, that the limit of this sequence is 0. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: $$2\cdot 2^n\color{red}\neq 4^n$$

Comment: See above. Usually the best thing to do in these limits is to divide through by the largest number to the power of $n$

Answer (score 5):

Let me compile the two comments by Maximilian Janisch and George Dewhirst into an answer.

Your mistake is $2\cdot 2^n = 4^n$. Actually, $4^n = (2^2)^n = (2^n)^2 =2^n\cdot 2^n$ and $2\cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$. Without this mistake, you would get $$\frac{2^n+3^n}{3^n+4^n} \leq \frac{2\cdot 3^n}{4^n} = 2\cdot\left(\frac 34\right)^n,$$ a useful upper bound that converges to $0$.

A common strategy is to divide both the numerator and the denominator by $4^n$ to get $$\frac{2^n+3^n}{3^n+4^n} = \frac{\left(\frac 24\right)^n + \left(\frac 34\right)^n}{\left(\frac 34\right)^n + 1}.$$ Now, note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} q^n = 0$ whenever $|q|<1$.

Comment: +1 I think we can get the bound $$a_n\le\frac{2\cdot3^n}{4^n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch, you are right, let me edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{2^n +3^n}{3^n+4^n}=\left(\dfrac34\right)^n\frac{\left(\dfrac23\right)^n+1}{\left(\dfrac34\right)^n+1}\to0\cdot\frac11.$$